# How do I calculate the edge of the viewport based on a vector and angle?

Tags: javascript, geometry, angle

First I would invite you to take a look at this demonstration so I can use the elements in this question as a reference: https://jsfiddle.net/krazyjakee/01rqec1e/2/

If you move the mouse around in the demo, you can see the red dot follow the mouse restricted by the edge of the blue square. This works perfectly with this logic.

```
const mouse = {
    x: e.pageX,
    y: e.pageY,
};

const target = block.getBoundingClientRect();
const targetCenter = {
    x: Math.floor(target.left + (target.width / 2)),
    y: Math.floor(target.top + (target.height / 2)),
};

const angle = Math.atan2(mouse.y - targetCenter.y, mouse.x - targetCenter.x);

const cosAngle = Math.abs(Math.cos(angle));
const sinAngle = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle));

const magnitude = target.width / 2 * sinAngle <= target.height / 2 * cosAngle ?
    target.width / 2 / cosAngle :
    target.height / 2 / sinAngle;

const targetEdge = {
    x: targetCenter.x + Math.cos(angle) * magnitude,
    y: targetCenter.y + Math.sin(angle) * magnitude,
};
```

I then take the result and use it to find the nearest point on the edge of the viewport with this:

```
const viewportMagnitude = {
    x: (viewport.width / target.width),
    y: (viewport.height / target.height),
};

const viewPortEdge = {
    x: (targetEdge.x - target.left) * viewportMagnitude.x,
    y: (targetEdge.y - target.top) * viewportMagnitude.y,
};
```

But if you imagine a line from the center of the blue square, through the red dot and through the mouse, it does not line up with the green square on the edge of the viewport. What do I need to tweak to get the green square to line up with the red square and mouse?

Answer (score 0):

Seems your `viewportMagnitude` approach cannot work right when square is not centered (and viewport is not square)

So you can use another approach.

x0,y0 is ray starting point - here  targetCenter.x,  targetCenter.y
x1,y1 and x2,y2 are corners coordinates of viewport  - here, I think, 0,0 and width,height

[corrected JS test](https://jsfiddle.net/01rqec1e/10/)

```
//preliminary
const x0 = targetCenter.x; 
const y0 = targetCenter.y; 

const x1 = 0;
const y1 = 0;

const x2 = viewport.width;
const y2 = viewport.height;

const vx = mouse.x - x0;
const vy = mouse.y - y0;

vx = mouse.x - x0
vy = mouse.y - y0

//ray equations (parametric form, t is parameter):
//just for reference, they do not take part in calculations
//x = x0 + vx * t
//y = y0 + vy * t

//potential border positions    
if vx > 0 then
   ex = x2
else
   ex = x1

if vy > 0 then
   ey = y2
else
   ey = y1

 //check for horizontal/vertical directions
if vx = 0 then
return cx = x0,  cy = ey,

if vy = 0 then
    return cx = ex, cy = y0


//in general case find times of intersections with horizontal and vertical edge line
  tx = (ex - x0) / vx
  ty = (ey - y0) / vy

 //and get intersection for smaller parameter value
 if tx <= ty then 
    return cx = ex, cy = y0 + tx * vy
 else
    return cx = x0 + ty * vx,  cy = ey
```

Comment: Thanks but what is "t", I presumed it was total x and y of the viewport? What is y0 and x0? Will that always be 0? I updated the example with these presumptions and found it to be way off. https://jsfiddle.net/krazyjakee/01rqec1e/6/

Comment: I added some description